# Tableau Line Graph doesn't connect the current month

Tags: tableau-api

Hello as you can see in the image,
I have created a worksheet in which I'm trying to show the line graph trend of the number of tickets per month per track level(see filters)

However when i turn on the filter " Show Current Month" to True,
The line graph doesnt connect to the the current month which is Jan 2016

Is this beacuse Jan is a new Year in the graph ?
What can be the solution to the issue ?

[Current month issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDkcz.png)

Comment: You cut off the most important part of the image - the top showing the Rows and Columns shelves.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you are using Continuous date field. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dates_continuous.html

And if your date field is continuous, then you only need one date field on the columns shelf (i.e. get rid of the blue Year([Event Date]) field from the Columns shelf and only keep the green one

Comment: Thanks Bernardo and Alex. It helped